# Initialise a board filled with StringVar() and update variables using Tkinter, Python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, visualization

I am implementing game of fifteen, and I realized the board would need to be built with string variables so that later I can update it. I tried using the following:
d is dimension inputted by user (say 3-> 3x3)

```
board = []
def initialize():
    numbers = d * d - 1
    global board
    blankx = d - 1
    blanky = d - 1

    # Fill board with stringvars
    v = tk.StringVar()
    for j in range(d):
        row = []
        for i in range(d):
            v.set(str(numbers))
            row.append(v)
            numbers -= 1
            if numbers == 0:
                v.set('_')
        board.append(row)
```

I'm getting a board of all zeros, while it should look like this:

8   7   6

5   4   3

2   1   _

Any tips? Also, on updating these variables?

Comment: You will need to move `v = tk.StringVar()` into your nested loop, otherwise you are just updating and appending the same instance of `StringVar()` over and over

Comment: think that's ok as it just calls the object. It updates it every time though within the loop. I changed it by adding get() and set() to the variable so the board[] itself looks fine. I just wonder how you visualize it with Tkinter, and update these variables.

Comment: re: _"I realized the board would need to be built with string variables so that later I can update it."_. That's not necessarily true. If you're using `Label` or `Entry` widgets, there's no requirement to use `StringVar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you would use a button sending some kind of identification to a common function when pressed, which then updates it and whatever else you want to do. A simple example.

```
"""store the variable in a dictionary whose key is the 
   row and column number
"""
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as tk     ## Python 2.x
else:
    import tkinter as tk     ## Python 3.x

from functools import partial

root=tk.Tk()

def callback(key):
    if variables_dict[key].get() == "_":
        variables_dict[key].set("Pushed")
    else:
        variables_dict[key].set("Error")

variables_dict={}
for j in range(3):
    for k in range(5):
        v = tk.StringVar()

        ## send same key to the callback function and use as
        ## dictionary's key
        key="%02d-%02d" % (j, k) 
        ## no need to keep a reference to the Button's class
        ## instance & all of not used modules within it
        tk.Button(root, textvariable=v,
                  command=partial(callback, key)).grid(row=j,
                  column=k, sticky="nsew")
        variables_dict[key]=v
        v.set('_')

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're only creating a single `StringVar`. Your problem statement was that you wanted one for each space on the board so you need to create the variable inside the loop:

```
for j in range(d):
    v = tk.StringVar()
    ...
```

Comment: Hm.. I get what you mean, so I still get the board[][] that I wanted, but later on when I want to refer to each element as a separate stringvar, it won't work. So now I put it into the 2nd loop ... and it should be ok?! I am calling these variables when visualizing it similarly as I'm looping through the board. I create a label for each iteration and set: textvariable=string_var. Yet, it doesn't get updated somehow. Any ideas? It concerns the setup() function in http://pastebin.com/FZ95vZDG if that's easier

Comment: @DóraJámbor: honestly, my suggestion is to not use `StringVar`. You can update labels without them.